# Iterating over a list of objects that implement a common interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, foreach, interface

I have an interface shared by several objects, defined as so:

```
public interface IConvertibleToListItem
{
    ListViewItem toListItem();
}
```

I have lists of objects that share this interface. I want to be able to do this:

```
refreshList(newsListView, _news);

private void refreshList(ListView lv, List<IConvertibleToListItem> items)
{
    lv.Items.Clear();
    foreach (IConvertibleToListItem item in items) { lv.Items.Add(item.toListItem()); }
}
```

But I get an error about the best overloaded method match having some invalid arguments.

Comment: Please show the *exact* error message - and ideally a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (I suggest you start following .NET naming conventions, too.)

Comment: Is `_news` of type `List<IConvertibleToListItem>`?

Comment: _news is of the type List<News>, which implements IConvertibleToListItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variance problem - `List<News>` is not compatible with `List<IConvertibleToListItem>`. For your method you can use `IEnumerable<IConvertibleToListItem>` since you are only iterating over the collection:

```
private void refreshList(ListView lv, IEnumerable<IConvertibleToListItem> items)
{
    lv.Items.Clear();
    foreach (IConvertibleToListItem item in items) { lv.Items.Add(item.toListItem()); }
}
```

if for some reason you need to use a `List` you can make your method generic:

```
private void refreshList<T>(ListView lv, List<T> items)
    where T : IConvertibleToListItem
{
    lv.Items.Clear();
    foreach (IConvertibleToListItem item in items) { lv.Items.Add(item.toListItem()); }
}
```